# How to use MaskFormatter and DocumentFilter together

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, documentfilter

I need to have a `JFormattedTextField` that allows only the input of `##-###**` where the hyphen is always present in the text field and the last 2 characters, represented by the `*`, can either be 2 letters of the alphabet (a-z/ A-Z) or nothing at all.

I know how to solve parts of this but not exactly sure how to bring everything together. I know that using a `MaskFormatter` of `##-###**` will give me the always present hyphen but there is no way for me to enforce the rule of the last 2 characters being either letters or nothing at all. Furthermore, the `MaskFormatter` will replace any deletion with the last valid insert which is undesirable.

I also know that I could use a `DocumentFilter` to only allow the format I want by using regexes, similar to this functionality but with a different regex:

```
public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, int length, String str, AttributeSet a)
        throws BadLocationException {

    String text = fb.getDocument().getText(0, fb.getDocument().getLength());
    text += str;
    if ((fb.getDocument().getLength() + str.length()
            - length) <= maxCharacters && text.matches("^[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]{0,1}$")) {
        super.replace(fb, offs, length, str, a);
    } else {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```

The problem I see with using this is that I would not be able to have the hyphen always present in the text field.

Can someone help me complete the bridge between these two desired functions?

Comment: _"can either be 2 letters of the alphabet (a-z/ A-Z) or nothing at all."_ This requirement is going to make it impossible to match a regex. You can't have two letters without first having one :-( I would maybe look into just doing focus validation instead of trying to do real time validation probably. You can use an `InputVerifier` to show an error message if the input is invalid

Comment: are you sure? I'm not the best on regexes but I remember reading that there are quantifiers that permit "zero or more times". you said "You can't have two letters without first having one" and I'm wondering if my question was misleading. there will always be something before the last 2 entries, but they will be numbers. Sample valid input would be "12-345" or "12-345AB"

Comment: You can match it, but remember, as discussed in another on of your questions, the input is coming in per letter, so the filtering is happening _per letter_. So you can't have `0AB` without first allowing `0A` to be typed in. But it can't be typed in, because the regex you want won't match it. You get what I'm saying? You said you want either 0 or 2 letters. But it's impossible to have 2 letters without first having 1. What if the user stops typing after the first letter?

Comment: well mostly I think. But wasn't that issue solved by adding each character entered into a string in the Filter? Sorry for my lack of understanding, I've never touched this sort of material until last week. I'm also wondering if I go the `InputVerifier` route, how would I be able to achieve the desired functionality of matching the specific pattern I need? Thanks for your time and effort btw

Comment: Say you type `00-0000` that's ok. But the next character you type, will go through the filter. Say you type `A`, it will not be allowed because the regex you want will only match say `00-0000` or `00-0000AA`. So there's no way to even type in `00-0000AA`. That's the point I'm getting at.

Comment: Ohh, I see what you're getting at now. Like I said my regex knowledge is low level, I thought there would be a way to make it work. So then if I don't filter in real time and use `InputVerifier`, would I still use a `MaskFormatter` of `##-###**`? Also, what would I use in the `InputVerifier` to validate the user input?

Answer (score 3):

> "there is no way for me to enforce the rule of the last 2 characters being either letters or numbers."

Sorry didn't see you were using a `MaskFormatter`. If you look at the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html), you'll see a chart of possible character formats

- `#`   Any valid number, uses Character.isDigit.
- `'`   Escape character, used to escape any of the special formatting characters.
- `U`   Any character (Character.isLetter). All lowercase letters are mapped to upper case.
- `L`   Any character (Character.isLetter). All upper case letters are mapped to lower case.
- `A`   Any character or number (Character.isLetter or Character.isDigit)
- `?`   Any character (Character.isLetter).
- `*`   Anything.
- `H`   Any hex character (0-9, a-f or A-F).

So you could actually just use `"##-####UU"`

---

**EDIT** using `InputVerifier`

```
import javax.swing.InputVerifier;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestMaskFormatter {

    private static final String REGEX = "^\\d{2}\\-\\d{4}([A-Z]{2})??";

    private static InputVerifier getInputVerifier() {
        InputVerifier verifier = new InputVerifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
                JTextField field = (JTextField) input;
                String text = field.getText();
                return text.matches(REGEX) || text.isEmpty();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {
                boolean valid = verify(input);
                if (!valid) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Must Match format: 00-0000AA");
                    JTextField field = (JTextField) input;
                    field.setText("");
                }
                return valid;
            }

        };
        return verifier;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTextField fieldWithVerifier = new JTextField(10);
        fieldWithVerifier.setInputVerifier(getInputVerifier());
        JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(fieldWithVerifier);
        panel.add(field1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
    }
}
```

Comment: oh nuts, it looks like I made a slip up in that second paragraph that contradicts the first. I meant to say "last 2 characters being either letters or *nothing at all*" Sorry, I edited it. That's why MaksFormatter was a problem for me.

Comment: See my edit using an `InputVerifer`, You can type anything, but once the field loses focus, it will be validated, and a message will pop up is the format is wrong

Comment: thanks for your edit, I tried it out and tried playing around with it but I still can't quite get what I need. Your answer shows how to verify input but I need the hyphen to always be showing like the MaskFormat of `##-###**` provides. An if I change `fieldWithVerifier` for a JFormattedTextField with a Mask, it does not work with the verifier correctly